# Register click events on an embedded pdf viewer

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, pdf, event-handling

For a project, we are using Chrome in --kiosk mode. Users can interact with the website in the kiosk through a touchscreen only. On this website is a javascript timer that counts down and after a minute returns to the landing page. When the page registers a user interaction, the timer is reset.

```
$(document).on('mousemove click mousedown', resetTimer);
```

This all works as it should, but one page has an embedded pdf viewer (the built-in Chrome pdf viewer). The $(document) returns a mousedown and mouseup event when the pdf is clicked with a mouse, but tapping the pdf on the touch screen registers no events.

When showing a regular page in the iframe, I can use the following code to handle events in the iframe, but it doesn't seem to work with the Chrome PDF viewer.

```
$('iframe').contents().on({
        mousedown: resetTimer,
        mouseup: resetTimer,
        mousemove: resetTimer,
        click: resetTimer
    });
```

I tried embedding the PDF using an iframe, embed and object element, but the result is the same for all.
I tried using PDFjs instead of the default Chrome PDF viewer, but it doesn't support pinch zooming.
I also tried using jQuery mobile, to handle touch events, but no touch events were returned on tapping or pinching the embedded PDF viewer.

Does anybody have any other ideas on how to reset the JS timer on user interaction in the embedded PDF?